# How to update progress bar from a series of inner methods in Winform 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a progress bar in the main form and there is a method called `MethodA()` in it. Inside in this `methodA()`, it calls another method `Class1.MethodB()` and inside in this `methodB()` it calls another method `Class2.MethodC()`. And this `MethodC()` calls another method `Class3.MethodD()`. In all these methods, some long running process are going on:

```
class MainForm : Form
{
    void MethodA()
    {
        // ...

        instanceOfClass1.MethodB();

        // ...
    }
}

class Class1
{
    void MethodB()
    {
        // ...

        instanceOfClass2.MethodC();

        // ...
    }
}

class Class2
{
    void MethodC()
    {
        // ...

        instanceOfClass3.MethodD();

        // ...
    }
}
```

The method calls are all instance method calls, not static calls.

How i can update progress bar value here ?. When the button clicks, the progress bar should run and ends when the `Class3.MethodD()` stops execution ?

How can we update the progress bar which is in the main form from other classes ? I cannot create an instance of the main form and pass as an argument to every classes. There are a lot of other controls in the main form.

Comment: by sending some interface which would allow this ... fx `inteface IProgress { SetProgress(..) }` then let Fx Form implement this interface and send the form to the ClassX

Comment: What method actually does the work and would be able to assess how much progress has taken place?

Comment: @PatrickTucci thanks for the reply. Actually all the method (methodA, methodB, methodC, methodD) does the work and some long running works are there in all these methods. So the progress bar value has to update within all these methods.

Comment: How would all those *independent* (void) methods know what kind of *Progress* to report? Do those methods work on the same object(s)? Can this progress be considered *consistent* (a determined, progressive work on a common set of objects)? At some point, each method, independently, needs to set a `ProgressBar.Value`. Do all methods know what value they need to set?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you can modify the other methods to change their parameters, then pass around an `IProgress<T>`. (The `T` is arbitrary, though if you only want to update a progress bar display then use `IProgress<Single>` with values `0-1.0` to represent 0 to 100%).

Avoid using `static` objects, methods or state to transmit progress information inside your program.

Something like this:

```
class MainForm
{
    private class MainFormProgress : IProgress<Single>
    {
        private readonly ProgressBar pb;
        private const Int32 _max = 10000; // Using values above 100 animate smoother if the ProgressBar is wider than 100 pixels.

        public MainFormProgress( ProgressBar pb )
        {
            this.pb = pb ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pb));
            this.pb.Minimum =    0;
            this.pb.Maximum = _max;
            this.pb.Value   =    0;
        }

        public void Report( Single value )
        {
            // You MAY need to wrap this in a call to BeginInvoke or Invoke if this is being run on a background thread.
            this.pb.Value = (Int32)( value * _max );
        }
    }

    void MethodA()
    {
        MainFormProgress progress = new MainFormProgress( this.progressBar );

        instanceOfClass1.MethodB( progress  );

        // ...
    }
}

class Class1
{
    void MethodB( IProgress<Single> progress )
    {
       // ...

        // do something

        progress.Report( 0.1 ); // we're 10% complete!

        instanceOfClass2.MethodC( progress );

        progress.Report( 0.75 ); // we're 75% complete!

        // ...
   }
}

// etc for the other classes
```

`IProgress<T>` can also be used in other contexts too, such as console-mode applications and SignalR in ASP.NET.